# how to call function while element content text has changed using apply or anything outside of angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

I need to call a javascript function when a particular element content text has changed. How to do this? I have tried this code but to no use.

I want to call a callback function when the #showRouteSubTypes element text has changed.

```
<label class="label" id="showRouteSubTypes">Main, Sub</label>
```

**Code**

```
<script>
    angular.element('#showRouteSubTypes').scope().apply(function(){alert("uu");})
</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: What would cause the element text to change? You should not be doing DOM manipulation if you use AngularJS.

Comment: why i am asking like this means, i can't able to add class for this while text has changed when i click edit option..so here if i use setTimeout mean, then it work well..but here i need callback function while it has changed..

Comment: function has been executed before the new value affected to that label element text

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you write. But my point is that if you are using Angular, you should not be listening for changes to an elements text. Especially not if you are the one changing that text.

Comment: can i do it from javascript function?

Comment: function fnShowSelectedItem(control){
  
  //setTimeout(function(){
   var idVal = $(control).html();
   $(control).hide();
   $(control+'Result').html("");
   var arrayOfselectedItem = idVal.split(',');
   $.each(arrayOfselectedItem,function (i,data){
    $(control+'Result').append('<div class="selectedMenu">'+data+'</div>');
   });
  //},100);
  
}

Comment: here i have use setTimeout. but i need this same result without using setTimeout(). so anything else to listen and after then update this to that new element..like as above code in comment..

Comment: in above function param i have pass id as argument(control)..

Comment: can we watch that process??